# uniwind with creating rows having only different values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongo query aggregation where i have data like this

```
[
    {
        "token" : "c1",
        "class" : "bscs",
        courses : ["ITM", "CS54", "KHE"]
    }
]
```

I am using **$unwind** to break courses which makes it

```
[
    {
        "token" : "c1",
        "class" : "bscs",
        courses : "ITM"
    },
    {
        "token" : "c1",
        "class" : "bscs",
        courses : "CS54"
    },
    {
        "token" : "c1",
        "class" : "bscs",
        courses : "KHE"
    }
]
```

What i want is, it should be like :-

```
[
    {
        "token" : "c1",
        "class" : "bscs",
        courses : "ITM"
    },
    {
        "token" : "",
        "class" : "",
        courses : "CS54"
    },
    {
        "token" : "",
        "class" : "",
        courses : "KHE"
    }
]
```

As i have a tabled structure where i need to show data, which is very complex and a lot of data from different queries is shown there so i can't update that. if its like this then i can show in table as 
[image]

My aggregation is

```
[   {.....}, // others projections and matches
   { 
    $unwind: {
     path: '$courses'
    }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `includeArrayIndex` option when running [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#pipe._S_unwind) and then use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) to set empty string if index is not equal to `0`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$courses",
            includeArrayIndex: "index"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            token: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$index", 0 ] }, "$token", "" ] },
            class: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$index", 0 ] }, "$class", "" ] },
            courses: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TYvQHPBOZtB)